# Every submodule of a cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module is a weight module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a highest weight $\mathfrak{g}$-module, such that there is a maximal vector $v_+$ and $U(\mathfrak{n}^-)\cdot v_+=V$. Where $v_+$ has weight $\lambda$. How do I show that every submodule is a weight module?

Denote the positive roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $\Delta^+=\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k\}$. I have tried considering $V$ as a weight module, with $V_{\lambda-\sum n_i \beta_i}$ with $n_i\in (\Bbb Z^+\cup \{0\})$, where then any submodule has to have an element that is a sum of elements of these weight spaces. But I couldn't construct a valid argument.

Perhaps my argument should be. Any element of a submodule $W$, must be equal to $\sum u_i v_+$ for $u_i\in U(\mathfrak{n}^-)$. Where $u_i$ are of height $\sum -n_i\beta_i$, and hence I have an element $\sum u_i v_+$ in the sum of weight spaces $\bigoplus_i V_{\lambda - \sum n_i \beta_i}$. This holds for any given element of $W$, and so we have a weight space decomposition of $W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to follow your argument. Here's how I would do it.

Let $w\in W$. Then$$\tag{1}w=v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_n,$$where each $v_i\in V_{\mu_i}$ and the weights $\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_n$ are distinct. We must show that each $v_i$ belongs to $W$. If not, we can choose a $w$ such that $(1)$ holds and $n$ is minimal; of course, $n\geqslant2$ and no $v_i$ belongs to $W$. Find $H\in\mathfrak h$ for which $\mu_1(H)\neq\mu_2(H)$. Then $H.w\in W$ and, on the other hand, $H.w=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k(H)v_k$. So$$H.w-\mu_1(H)w=\bigl(\mu_2(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_2+\cdots+\bigl(\mu_n(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_n\in W.$$It follows from the choice of $w$ that $v_2\in W$, which is absurd.

Comment: How do you conclude that $v_2\in W$? Was $H$ additionally chosen to make all of $\mu_i-\mu_1$ vanish at $H$, for $i\ne 2$? Or there is an induction here that I can't work out?

Comment: I deduced it from the way I chose $n$ and from the fact that $n-1<n$.

Comment: @user462339 Note that the equality$$H.w-\mu_1(H)w=\bigl(\mu_2(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_2+\cdots+\bigl(\mu_n(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_n\in W$$ expresses $H.w-\mu_1(H)w$ as the sum of $n-1$ weight vectors. It follows from the definition of $n$ that each one of them belongs to $W$. In particular, $\bigl(\mu_2(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_2\in W$ and, since $\mu_1(H)\neq\mu_2(H)$, $v_2\in W$.

Comment: So the mimimality of $n$ works only because we have a scalar multiple of $n$ on the LHS. I was getting confused because having minimality of $n$ things summing to $w$ doesn't tell us anything about minimality for $H\cdot w - \mu_1(H)w$ unless this was a scalar multiple of $w$.

Comment: @user462339 I don't understand your comment. There is no $n$ on the LHS.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. That part should read "scalar multiple of $w$ on the LHS" everything else is typed as intended. I meant that if we claim $w=v_1+\dots+v_n$, then we take $w-v_n=v_1+\dots+v_{n-1}$, then we can't say anything of interest. But since you have shown that $zw= z_2v_2+\dots+ z_nv_n$ we then see that:
$$w= \frac{z_2}{z}v_2+\dots + \frac{z_n}{z}v_n,$$
contradicting the minimality of $w$.(for $z,z_2,\dots,z_n\in \Bbb C$)

Comment: @user462339 No, I am not assuming that $H.w-\mu_1(H)w$ is a scalar multiple of $w$. I am only using the fact that it belongs to $W$ and that I was able to express it as the sum of $n-1$ weight vectors. It follows from the minimality of $n$ that each of these weight vectors belong to $W$ too. And since $\bigl(\mu_2(H)-\mu_1(H)\bigr)v_2\in W$ and $\mu_2(H)-\mu_1(H)\neq0$, $v_2\in W$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Shouldn't it be "...on the other hand, $H.w=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k(H)v_k$" instead of "$H.w=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k(H)w$"?

Comment: @M.C. I've edited my answer. Thank you.